# IE automation to send mac address to website and output organization

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, automation

I have been given a list of a thousand mac addresses to lookup which company they belong to.

Instead of maunally searching http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/public.html, I would like to read each mac address from a file and output the organization into another file.

Right now, this is how the powershell script looks like:

```
 $mac = '00-00-00'  
 $ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
 $ie.Visible = $true
 $ie.navigate('http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/public.html')

 while($ie.Busy){sleep -mil 100}


 $ie.Document.getElementById("x").value=$mac
 $ie.Document.getElementById("submit").Click()
```

When I run the script, it launches the website http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/public.html, and it prints "00-00-00" to the text box, but it does not click the submit button"

Here is the relevant source of the website:

```
<input name="x" size="30" type="text" value="" /><input name="submit2" type="submit" value="Search!" />
```

1) How to make it "click"
2) How to write the output to somewhere (i.e. console, file, etc, etc)

Thank you!

EDIT:

I noticed the following error is output to console:

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

```
At C:\sandbox\get-org.ps1:11 char:46
+      $ie.Document.getElementById("submit").Click <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Click:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automating Internet Explorer is overkill in this case. IEEE supports a more friendly URL syntax where you just embed the OUI as part of your request:

```
$mac = "00-01-02"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$html = $wc.DownloadString("http://standards.ieee.org/cgi-bin/ouisearch?$mac")
```

The `$html` variable contains the very brief HTML for the search results page. You can further filter or process it however you would like.

Please note: They may have some throttling in place or other terms of use for the service, so you may not want to issue requests to the server as fast as PowerShell can. Consider adding a `Start-Sleep 1` after each query to delay the requests by one second to relieve the load you will suddenly create on their service.

Comment: Thank you! I'll be especially careful about spacing out requests from powershell to the website.